# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un input para un tipo BigDecimal en un form de jsp?

Tags: java, formularios, jsp, input, bigdecimal

Estoy intentando realizar un formulario en jsp y tengo una variable que es tipo BigDecimal. Me gustaría hacer un input para que el cliente ingrese el valor de esa variable pero no sé cómo sería correctamente. He buscado en internet y he intentado informarme pero no he dado con la solución. Intenté realizarlos con `type="number"` pero no funcionó. ¿Podríais ayudarme, por favor?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, revisa [ask] y [help]. En concreto, pon el código probado (como un [mcve]) y explica qué error te has encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

Agregar `step="0.01"`a los `<input type="number" />` parámetros:

```
<input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" max="2500" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo he hecho es que el valor que ingrese el cliente lo escriba en un  `<input type="text"/>` por ejemplo, a partir de esto puedes crear un bigDecimal con el valor de este input (en el constructor).